# How to add extra imports to my js files during compilation. Want to theme my react components

Tags: node.js, webpack

I want to configure the following set up for developing a react app and it's components with a possibility of css theming.

- Each React component will have a separate js file, and will
  explicitly import its corresponding "component.css" file.
- The css explicitly imported in the js file will have the essential none themed css for that component.
- At compile time I want Webpack to be configured with a theme name, and directories where it needs to look for the theme files.
- During the loading of component js files, the compiler will detect the .css imports in the form of "component.css", for each of those imports it will look for a theme .css file in the form of "component.themename.css" in the configured directories and subdirectories.
- If a theme file is found the compiler will add the import for that file into the js file being loaded.

With the above set up I want to be able to define theme css files for each of my components separately and then use the appropriate theme file according to a theme of my choosing.

Is there anything already available that would achieve something like this? What's the best way of implementing something like this? A loader? a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve the above quite nicely with a custom css webpack loader and plugin.

The plugin searches for available theme files in the given directories.

The loader is added to the start of the loader chain. It is configured with a theme name and a reference to an object containing theme files found by the plugin.

For every css file imported it looks for a theme file with the same name and a .theme. suffix. Eg. for component.css it will look for component.theme.css in the given directories.

If it finds a theme .css file it appends it's contents to the css being loaded, and adds the theme file to the webpack watched dependencies.

Here's the code to achieve this:

webpack.config.js

```
const themeLoaderPlugin = new ThemeLoaderPlugin({theme: "themeName", dirs: ["dir/to/search/for/themefiles"] });
const css = {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader',
                {
                loader: path.resolve('/path/to/loader.js'),
                options: {
                    theme: "themeName",
                    filesContainer: themeLoaderPlugin.getState()
                }
            }]
    };
const config = {
...
    plugins: [
        themeLoaderPlugin
    ]
}
```

loader code:

```
const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = function(source) {
    let options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this);
    let themeName = options.theme;
    let files = options.filesContainer.files;
    let fileName = this.resourcePath.match(/.*(\/|\\)(.*)\..*/)[2];
    let themeFileName = fileName + "." + themeName + ".";
    for (const file of files) {
        if(file.indexOf(themeFileName) >= 0){
            let contents = fs.readFileSync(file);
            source = source + "\n" +  contents.toString("UTF-8");
            this.dependency(path.resolve(file));
        }
    }
    return source;
};
```

Plugin code:

```
const glob = require('fast-glob')

module.exports = class ThemeLoaderPlugin {
    constructor(options){
        this.options = options;
        this.state = {};
    }

    getState(){
        return this.state;
    }

    refreshFiles() {
        this.state.files = getThemeFiles(this.options.dirs, this.options.theme);
    }

    apply(compiler){
        compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap("ThemeFilesScanPlugin", ()=>{
            this.refreshFiles();
        });
        compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap("ThemeFilesScanPlugin", () =>{
            this.refreshFiles();
        });
    }
};

function getThemeFiles(paths, themeName){
    let res = [];
    for (const path of paths) {
        let options = {
            cwd:path,
            ignore: "**/node_modules/**",
            absolute: true
        };
        res.push(...glob.sync("**/*." + themeName +".*", options));
    }
    return res;
}
```